# Android custom ArrayAdapter with custom object

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I am new for Android development.

I was trying to implement a custom `ArrayAdapter` to accept custom object in Android Studio.

I have referenced the source code from some tutorial, but my screen output was improper that the custom object only fill in the `TextView` which link with the `textViewResourceId` of `ArrayAdapter` , but not the custom object's properties fill in all `EditText` in the layout appropriately.

I tried to remove `textViewResourceId` parameter in the constructor of `ArrayAdapter` to fix the problem, but Android Studio returned error - **You must supply a resource ID for a TextView**

I want the properties of custom object fill in all `EditText` and no error message be returned, can anyone give me a hint?

Here is my layout:

**row_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/row_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/row_no"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/row_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my custom object:

**Row.java**

```
public class Row
{
    public int RowNo;
    public String RowText;

    public Row(int no, String text)
    {
        this.RowNo = no;
        this.RowText = text;
    }
}
```

Here is my custom ArrayAdapter:

**RowAdapter.java**

```
public class RowAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Row> {

    private final Activity _context;
    private final ArrayList<Row> rows;

    static class ViewHolder
    {
        EditText RowNo;
        EditText RowText;
    }

    public RowAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Row> rows)
    {
        super(context,R.layout.row_layout, R.id.row_id ,rows);
        this._context = context;
        this.rows = rows;
    }

    public View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if(convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = _context.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.RowNo = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_no);
            holder.RowText = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_text);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.RowNo.setText(rows.get(position).RowNo);
        holder.RowText.setText(rows.get(position).RowText);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Here is my Activity class:

**RowActivity.java**

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.row_list_page);

        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        ArrayList<Row> rows = new ArrayList<Row>();
        rows.add(new Row(1,"Test"));
        rows.add(new Row(2,"Test"));
        rows.add(new Row(3"Test"));

        RowAdapter adapter = new RowAdapter(this,rows);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: you can use `BaseAdapter`.

Comment: I think you wrote these yourself instead of implementing with the help of IDE. Otherwise there will be `override` annotation as well as `getView` method not `GetView`. Neither it's related to xamarin.

Comment: Shree Krisbna: Yes, you are right. Next time I will use intelligence sence to avoid this kind of mistakes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working adapter code

```
public class RowAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Row> {

    private final Activity _context;
    private final ArrayList<Row> rows;

    public class ViewHolder
    {
        EditText RowNo;
        EditText RowText;
    }

    public RowAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Row> rows)
    {
        super(context,R.layout.row_layout, R.id.row_id ,rows);
        this._context = context;
        this.rows = rows;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if(convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = _context.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.RowNo = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_no);
            holder.RowText = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_text);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.RowNo.setText(""+rows.get(position).RowNo);
        holder.RowText.setText(rows.get(position).RowText);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Your getting exception at             holder.RowNo.setText(rows.get(position).RowNo);

so replace it with
holder.RowNo.setText(""+rows.get(position).RowNo);

Answer (score 1):

Change with below code:-

**RowAdapter.java**

```
 public class RowAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    
        private final Context _context;
        private final ArrayList<Row> rows;
    
        public RowAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Row> rows)
        {
            this._context = context;
            this.rows = rows;
        }
    
          @Override
          public int getCount() {
              return rows.size();
          }
    
          @Override
          public Object getItem(int position) {
              return rows;
          }
    
          @Override
          public long getItemId(int position) {
              return position;
          }
    
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    
               LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context
                  .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    
               View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null,true);
                
               EditText RowNo = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_no);
               EditText RowText = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_text);
    
               RowNo.setText(rows.get(position).RowNo);
               RowText.setText(rows.get(position).RowText);
    
            return rowView;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

This method is called to get view object.
In your code there is `GetView`, not `getView`

Answer (score 0):

change your

```
public View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

with

```
@Override
```

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)

and

```
holder.RowNo.setText(rows.get(position).RowNo);
```

with

```
holder.RowNo.setText(""+rows.get(position).RowNo);
```