# ListView doesn't show the list of items it only shows the package what to do? -Android

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite

I don't know what to do anymore please help, the listview doesn't get the items inside the database it just shows the package something.

//from the database

```
   public ArrayList<Question> getAllQuestions(){
    ArrayList<Question> questionList = new ArrayList<>();
    db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + QuestionsTable.TABLE_NAME, null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            Question question = new Question();
            question.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable._ID)));
            question.setQuestion(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_QUESTION)));
            question.setOption1(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION1)));
            question.setOption2(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION2)));
            question.setOption3(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION3)));
            question.setOption4(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION4)));
            question.setAnswer(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_ANSWER)));
            question.setCategoryID(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_CATEGORY_ID)));
            questionList.add(question);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
    return questionList;
}
```

//from the view question class

```
   private void questionList(){
    QuizDbHelper dbHelper = QuizDbHelper.getInstance(this);
    final ArrayList<Question> questionList = dbHelper.getAllQuestions();
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,questionList);
    lvQuestions.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

and it shows this

[It doesn't show what's inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oKjS.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android custom ArrayAdapter with custom object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36862968/android-custom-arrayadapter-with-custom-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the default `ArrayAdapter` which can only show strings. What you are seeing is the result to calling `toString()` method of the `Question` class.

In this case you have to create your own adapter and implement the logic of rendering each row with your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `toString` of Question class or subclass ArrayAdapter and override `getView` functions to set necessary text, something like this:

```
@Override
public @NonNull View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView,
            @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    final TextView view = (TextView)createViewFromResource(mInflater, position, convertView, parent, mResource);
    view.setText(questions.get(position).getQuestion());

    return view;
}
```